# I have a working bisection search, but I do not fully understand my code. Does it look appropriate to you?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What messes with my head is the length of the lists and the indexing of the lists. Here is my code:

```
def bisect(t, word):
    temp_t = t[:]
    index = int(len(t) / 2) - 1
    while t[index] != word:
        if len(temp_t) <= 1:
            return -1
        temp_index = int(len(temp_t) / 2)
        print(index)
        if temp_t[temp_index] < word:
            del temp_t[:temp_index+1]
            index += int(len(temp_t) / 2)
        elif temp_t[temp_index] > word:
            del temp_t[temp_index:]
            index -= len(temp_t) - int(len(temp_t) / 2)
    return index
```

Now, I only got it working after I added the "- 1" to the index. But that got me thinking: why should I not add "- 1" to the temp index every time as well? You know, since Python starts counting at 0 and all that.

EDIT: I wrote new code based on your input (specifically, to avoid creating unnecessary temporary variables) and the code is easier for me to understand. Here is the new version:

```
def bisect(t, word):
index = int(len(t) / 2) - 1
lower = 0
upper = len(t)
while t[index] != word:
    if len(t[lower:upper]) <= 1:
        return -1
    middle = int(len(t[lower:upper]) / 2)
    if t[lower:upper][middle] < word:
        lower = index + 1
        index += int(len(t[lower:upper]) / 2)
    elif t[lower:upper][middle] > word:
        upper = index
        index -= len(t[lower:upper]) - int(len(t[lower:upper]) / 2)
return index
```

Comment: Why are you using `del`? You don't want to *modify* your list while searching it.

Comment: @chepner OP created a copy of `t` in `temp_t`, and just returns the index.

Comment: I know; there's no reason to, though. A search is a not a destructive operation; there's no sense in turning it *into* one, even on a copy that leaves the original unmodified.

Comment: The typical way to handle this is to track and update the upper and lower bounds of which subsection you want to search.

Comment: @chepner Algorithmically it's likely not the best way to solve this, but the list `t` which is passed in is not modified at all, so from the outside it _is_ non-destructive to the list passed in. For the _user_ of this `bisect` the creation of a temporary list and deletion of elements is just an implementation detail.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa And that's not a mistake you can make if there's no copy to begin with.

Comment: @chepner I did not yet try to understand the algorithm, I just wanted to say that creating temporaries is not necessarily a problem in itself. It *is* a problem insofar that this code is harder to understand.

Comment: Although non-destructive, doesn't this algorithm by deleting sublists increase algorithm complexity?  Binary search is normally O(log(n)), but this algorithm perhaps is O(n*log(n)).

Comment: You new code is still making copies: `t[lower:upper]` creates a new list that copies a *portion* of the original list; it's not just a constant-time view into the original list.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation, and is not a way to have research, design or coding work done for you.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than working with an actively shrinking copy of the list, just work with an explicit set of indices bracketing the portion of the list still to search.

The three indices of interest are

1. `low`, such that if `x < low`, then `t[x] != word`
2. `high`, such that if `x > high`, then `t[x] != word`
3. `mid`, such that `low <= mid <= high`.

The *exact* value of `mid` doesn't matter, as long as it satisfies #3. For purposes of correctness, it suffices that either `low` increases or `high` decreases at each point, so that the *range* `[low, high]` is strictly shrinking. (For optimality, you use the fact that `high - low` is roughly cut in half at each step, ensuring a logarithmic number of iterations.)

```
def bisect(t, word):
    low = 0
    high = len(t) - 1
    while low <= high:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        if t[mid] == word:
            return mid
        elif t[mid] > word:
            # Continue with the smaller half.
            high = mid - 1
        else:
            # Continue with the larger half.
            low = mid + 1
    return -1
```

`low` and `high` are initialized so as to encompass the entire list. Each iteration of the loop restricts the portion of the list that could still contain the desired `word`.